# get 2 column values to 2 columns for 1 row (or comma-separated)

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a problem where I have to alter another programmer's very large SQL query.
My problem is described by this table:

```
+--------+-----------+---------------+-------------------------+
|   Id   | ProductId |    Barcode    |        CreatedAt        |
+--------+-----------+---------------+-------------------------+
|  30665 |    312118 | 4054065383840 | 2017-03-13 18:37:13.130 |
| 128600 |    312118 | 4054065383857 | 2017-05-22 13:26:48.683 |
+--------+-----------+---------------+-------------------------+
```

So as you can see, a product has 2 barcodes. In our query, I need to display these 2 barcodes in 2 columns, instead of 2 different rows, as barcode1 and barcode2, or some such.

```
  SELECT ISNULL(pp.Barcode,'') AS BarCode
  FROM (...) c
  LEFT JOIN ProductBarcode pp on pp.ProductId=c.VariantProductId
```

This is the query in use atm.
Hopefully I explained it well enough.
Thanks in advance,
Rasmus.

EDIT: db is MSSQL

Comment: I have been fiddling with this for some time now and i find it quite interesting, tomorrow i will try to continue cause i am going home now

Answer (score 1):

Use `pivot` query , much effective in this scenario. Use more row numbers if there are more than 2 barcodes as `barcode1,barcode2,barcode3`

```
SELECT productid
    ,[1] AS Barcode1
    ,[2] AS Barcode2
FROM (
    SELECT productid
        ,barcode
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY productid ORDER BY barcode
            ) rn
    FROM #mytable
    ) my
pivot(max(barcode) FOR rn IN ([1], [2])) AS pvt
```